# Would the Super User community be interested in a Soldering post?

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog

My TV has finally reached it's doom, and the convergence chips have gone out.  I've ordered new chips and will be removing the olds to be replaced with the new.  This will require de-soldering the old chips and soldering on the new ones.  I was thinking that I could turn this into a blog post about soldering (I would avoid the topic of TV's).  This isn't exactly the most common topic for Super User and may be a bit off-topic for even the blog.  I wanted to get the communities thoughts and feelings on such a post.

Comment: Sounds more appropriate to [electronics.se] to me, but we always need more on the blog...

Comment: I'd be interested in reading that.

Comment: @Mokubai they don't have a blog setup just yet.

Comment: @KronoS - Sounds like you have your answer.  I also would like to read it.  Since EE doesn't have a blog I would think it would fall to Superuser to host the content.

Comment: I agree with @Mokubai, SuperUser is more Software and Hardware for PC's and the like

Comment: We've previously closed questions on SU that deal with this type of content as not falling within scope. I don't have an opinion either way, just FYI.